# can sklearn's KNN Imputer work with specific rows within a dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, imputation

I have a pandas dataframe with some NaN values and I am trying to use the KNN imputer to fill them. I want the imputer to pick 'neighbors' based on a specific parameter, in this case it should only impute based on values with the same "patient_id". The missing values are some medical analysis results.

I tried to solve this problem by creating a list of unique "patient_id", using:

`patient_list=data['patient_id'].unique()`

then I iterated through the list with 'patient_id' masking, then merging all the sub-dataframes together, with:

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
knn = KNNImputer(missing_values=np.nan)

data_imputed = pd.DataFrame()

for patient_id in patient_list:
    X = knn.fit_transform(data[data['patient_id']==patient_id])
    X_ = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = data.columns)
    data_imputed.merge(X_, on=['patient_id','visit_month','visit_id'], how='left', copy=False)
```

but it is giving me a ValueError:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1187), indices imply (4, 1198)`

My original dataframe has 1198 columns, so how did 11 columns go missing? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Does your original dataset have any columns that are consist _entirely_ of NaN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
knn = KNNImputer(missing_values=np.nan)

data_imputed = []

for patient_id in patient_list:
    X = knn.fit_transform(data[data['patient_id']==patient_id])
    X_ = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = data.columns)
    data_imputed.append(X_, on=['patient_id','visit_month','visit_id'], how='left', copy=False)

data_imputed = pd.concat(data_imputed)
```

Comment: Use a list to store your outputs X_ and append after the loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).